# Merging different files in Java

Tags: java, merge, split, digital-signature

I have data files (e.g. text, image, …) and a digital signature of these files. I need to merge them into one file and send this file over a network. Is it possible to merge two or more different files into one, so I can later split that one file into several files, as it was before the merge? This split and merge would have to be done using my program written in Java.

Comment: Sure. Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: @GhostCat no, i dont have any idea how to do that

Comment: Hint: you don't need to merge stuff yourself. Java has classes that allow you to create zip archives by code... And then add files. Just use a search engine..

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `tar` file or a `zip` file:

Creating `tar`-files in java: https://github.com/kamranzafar/jtar

Creating `zip`-files in java: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/